# How to disable ale plugin by default in Vim?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm using https://github.com/w0rp/ale plugin. But it makes vim less responsive... I have a bind for `ALETooggle` on `<leader>l`.

It would be nice to have it disabled by default and enable by keyboard shortcut when wanted, I tried to put `ALEDisable` on my `.vimrc` but it gives me the error below

```
Error detected while processing /Users/daniel/.vimrc:
line   94:
E492: Not an editor command: ALEDisable   
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Here is a sample `.vimrc` that would trigger the problem

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
Plugin 'w0rp/ale'
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required

noremap <leader>l :ALEToggle<CR>
ALEDisable
```

Comment: Have you looked at vim's native package manager (e.g. `:help pack-add`) and considered placing this in the `opt` folder?  Seems like that would work well.  Certainly you could create a bind to perform a `:packadd ale`

Comment: I'm using Vundle for managing plugins, does the package manager changes anything about getting `ALEDisable` to work at `.vimrc`?

Comment: @geckos `ALEDisable` fails because plugins are loaded after vimrc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most elegant solution is to use a better plugin manager like [Plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) or [Dein](https://github.com/shougo/dein.vim). **Why?** Because they're well maintained and much more faster and efficient than the current plugin  manager you use. And most importantly they support lazy loading of plugins with ease.

For your purpose of loading the plugin on map, you can do either of these :

```
Plug 'w0rp/ale', { 'on':  'ALEToggle' }
```

or

```
call dein#add('w0rp/ale',{'on_cmd': 'ALEToggle'})
```

the same lazy loading maybe possible with vundle too i guess, but believe me, it's worth using either vim-plug or dein, cause they're super fast and intuitive.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that vundle was slow,

Answer (score 19):

The ALE plugin provides an option named `g:ale_enabled` to disable ALE by default, so this way is plugin manager agnostic.

If you set `g:ale_enabled` to `0` then ALE is disabled for any buffer.
Also the plugin provides an option to control ALE availability based on file name.
Here is an example found with `:h g:ale_enabled`:

```
" Disable linting for all minified JS files.
let g:ale_pattern_options = {'\.min.js$': {'ale_enabled': 0}}
```

You can enable ALE using `:ALEEnable` or `:ALEToggle` when you want to enable it.

Comment: This is very useful. I'm using vim-plug right now and is being very pleasant since it make my vi sessions much lighter.

Comment: :ALEToggle (Capital T) -- unable to edit because edits must be 6+ chars :)